# Is it possible to combine background RGB with URL?

Tags: html, css

Is this possible? My code is:

```
.w-categories li:hover{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;        
}
```

But when I hover over the `li` , it removes the side background.

No hover

[image: http://screencloud.net/v/x1XU]

On hover

[image: http://screencloud.net/v/fmzr]

Background image: `background: url(../images/w_icon_tag.png) no-repeat 5px 10px;`

Comment: `background` replaces all background properties with whatever you specify (including `background-image`), so you need to be more specific, i.e. use `background-color`.

Comment: thanks bud, that's what I forgot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `background-color: rgba(...);` instead of `background: rgba(...);`.

Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/MRSallee/D97n9/

Comment: thanks buddy. I just forgot to do the background-color for the hover.. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to combine. <kbd>[See Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background)</kbd>

Check out this <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23JNw/)</kbd>

```
background:url(../images/w_icon_tag.png) no-repeat 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```